# How to get current page on an html website?

Tags: html

Found this great kind of share buttons that don't require any javascript, and seem fairly light on the page, but how do I make it find the current_page address so it can share that to these social medias (I just put 2 social medias but there are lots of buttons)?

```
<!-- Sharingbutton Facebook -->
<a class="resp-sharing-button__link" href="https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php
    $url="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    echo $url;
?>" target="_blank" aria-label="">
  <div class="resp-sharing-button resp-sharing-button--facebook resp-sharing-button--small"><div aria-hidden="true" class="resp-sharing-button__icon resp-sharing-button__icon--solid">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M18.77 7.46H14.5v-1.9c0-.9.6-1.1 1-1.1h3V.5h-4.33C10.24.5 9.5 3.44 9.5 5.32v2.15h-3v4h3v12h5v-12h3.85l.42-4z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<!-- Sharingbutton Twitter -->
<a class="resp-sharing-button__link" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=&amp;url=" target="_blank" aria-label="">
  <div class="resp-sharing-button resp-sharing-button--twitter resp-sharing-button--small"><div aria-hidden="true" class="resp-sharing-button__icon resp-sharing-button__icon--solid">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M23.44 4.83c-.8.37-1.5.38-2.22.02.93-.56.98-.96 1.32-2.02-.88.52-1.86.9-2.9 1.1-.82-.88-2-1.43-3.3-1.43-2.5 0-4.55 2.04-4.55 4.54 0 .36.03.7.1 1.04-3.77-.2-7.12-2-9.36-4.75-.4.67-.6 1.45-.6 2.3 0 1.56.8 2.95 2 3.77-.74-.03-1.44-.23-2.05-.57v.06c0 2.2 1.56 4.03 3.64 4.44-.67.2-1.37.2-2.06.08.58 1.8 2.26 3.12 4.25 3.16C5.78 18.1 3.37 18.74 1 18.46c2 1.3 4.4 2.04 6.97 2.04 8.35 0 12.92-6.92 12.92-12.93 0-.2 0-.4-.02-.6.9-.63 1.96-1.22 2.56-2.14z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Source: http://sharingbuttons.io/

Comment: Add this into html of your page

Comment: Sorry, what kind of info do you need that the stuff like $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in your source doesn't already provide?